# Check if publishReplay().refCount() has observers or not

Tags: rxjs

I define an Observable like this:

```
const obs$ = Observable.create(...)
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount();
```

So that it puts a ReplaySubject(1) between my source Observable and all observers.

Since ReplaySubject has in its state the number of observers (via its `observers` array property), how is it possible to access the ReplaySubject from `obs$`?

I actually only need to know if `obs$` has any observers or not. RxJS4 had [a hasObservers() method](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2232) on Subject, but it got removed in RxJS5. How can I achieve this with RxJS5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about your usage but for my needs I created a custom operator that allowed me to transparently perform side-effects (similar to tap) based on the state of the refCount. It just does a pass-through subscription and duck-punches the sub/unsub. The callback gets the current refCount and the previous so that you can tell the state and direction. I like using an operator for this since I can insert it at any point in my stream. If you simply want a binary output for whether there are any subscriptions or not it could be easily modified for that.

```js
const { Observable, Observer, interval } = rxjs;
const { publishReplay, refCount } = rxjs.operators;

const tapRefCount = (onChange) => (source) => {
  let refCount = 0;

  // mute the operator if it has nothing to do
  if (typeof onChange !== 'function') {
    return source;
  }
  // mute errors from side-effects
  const safeOnChange = (refCount, prevRefCount) => {
    try {
      onChange(refCount, prevRefCount);
    } catch (e) {
    }
  };
  
  // spy on subscribe
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    const subscription = source.subscribe(observer);
    const prevRefCount = refCount;
    refCount++;
    safeOnChange(refCount, prevRefCount);
    
    // spy on unsubscribe
    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
      const prevRefCount = refCount;
      refCount--;
      safeOnChange(refCount, prevRefCount);
    };
  });
};

const source = interval(1000).pipe(
  publishReplay(1),
  refCount(),
  tapRefCount((refCount, prevRefCount) => { console.log('refCount', refCount, prevRefCount > refCount ? 'down': 'up'); })
);

const firstSub = source.subscribe((x) => { console.log('first', x); });
let secondSub;
setTimeout(() => {
  secondSub = source.subscribe((x) => { console.log('second', x); });
}, 1500);
setTimeout(() => {
  firstSub.unsubscribe();
}, 4500);
setTimeout(() => {
  secondSub.unsubscribe();
}, 5500);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@rc/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

The typescript version:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';

export const tapRefCount = (
  onChange: (refCount: number, prevRefCount: number) => void
) => <T>(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> => {
  let refCount = 0;

  // mute the operator if it has nothing to do
  if (typeof onChange !== 'function') {
    return source;
  }

  // mute errors from side-effects
  const safeOnChange = (refCount, prevRefCount) => {
      try {
        onChange(refCount, prevRefCount);
      } catch (e) {
    }
  };

  // spy on subscribe
  return Observable.create((observer: Observer<T>) => {
    const subscription = source.subscribe(observer);
    const prevRefCount = refCount;
    refCount++;
    safeOnChange(refCount, prevRefCount);

    // spy on unsubscribe
    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
      const prevRefCount = refCount;
      refCount--;
      safeOnChange(refCount, prevRefCount);
    };
  }) as Observable<T>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with this solution for now. My use case is, I'm creating a lib exposing ~10 observables. And I want a sort of `getOverview()` function that, when called, shows the number of subscribers each of those 10 observables has. The ideal scenario would be a prototype patch on Observable to have `obs$.observersCount()` on those 10 Observables. But I'll go with this solution and store the refCounts of each observable in my `getOverview.js` module.

Comment: @amaurymartiny If this is the solution you are accepting you might want to actually accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

The `Subject` class has a public property called `observers` (see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.10/src/Subject.ts#L28)

So you can use just:

```
const s = new Subject();

...

if (s.observers.length > 0) {
  // whatever
}
```

Be aware that `refCount` returns an Observable so you won't be able to do what I mentioned above. However, you can provide your own Subject instance to `publishReplay` as the third argument and use `s.observers` on that, see http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-publishReplay

Comment: Would there be a way to patch Observable to have `obs$`, as defined in my original post, have a `obs$.getReplaySubject()` method that returns the custom Subject I passed into publishReplay as a 3rd argument (or into multicast)?

Comment: I don't think so and I wouldn't even recommend doing that. It's better to leave this to `Subject`