# How to get count of all uncompleted subscription left by each component or page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

1. In Ionic app, page is just a component.
2. I want to check total subscription left uncompleted by each page. Meaning they are doing background work which is not needed.
3. Suppose i have a `pageChanged$` which notifies when a page is changed.

**My current try**

```
    let activeSubscriptions = 0;
    let originalUnsubscribe = Subscription.prototype.unsubscribe;
    Subscription.prototype.unsubscribe = function (...args) {
      activeSubscriptions--;
      return originalUnsubscribe.call(this, ...args);
    }
    let originalSubscribe = Observable.prototype.subscribe;
    Observable.prototype.subscribe = function (...args) {
      activeSubscriptions++;
      return originalSubscribe.call(this, ...args);
    }

    let pageChanged$ = new Subject<string>();
    let lastActiveSubs = 0;
    let lastName = 'Start';
    pageChanged$
      .subscribe((pageName) => {
        console.log(`${lastName} += ${activeSubscriptions - lastActiveSubs}`)
        lastActiveSubs = activeSubscriptions
        lastName = pageName
      })
```

1. Can you provide any better way or improvements?
2. When a page 'A' is pushed on top of page 'B', is page 'B' destroyed or cached?

Comment: 2. : Cached. A page get's destroyed when it's deleted from the navigation stack. Using `.setRoot` or popping the page from the stack will destroy the page.

Comment: 1: This answers a similar problem using a `tapRefCount` operator which you could possibly use:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976825/check-if-publishreplay-refcount-has-observers-or-not/49980784#49980784

Answer (score 0):

What I do is creating an array of subscriptions where there are one or more Observables to listen to. 
Whenever I create a subscription, I add it to that array. Then, when ngOnDestroy is hit, I go through all of them and unsubscribe :

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  templateUrl: 'myselector.html'
})
export class APage {
   subscriptions : Array<Subscription> = new Array<Subscription>();

   ngOnInit() {
      let a_new_subscription = someObservable.subscribe(someFunction);
      this.subscriptions.push(a_new_subscription);
      //Add as many subscriptions as created
   }

   //...

   ngOnDestroy(){
     this.subscriptions.forEach(
        subscription => {
           subscription.unsubscribe();   
        }
     )
   }
}
```

Comment: yes, that is solution to 'When to unsubscribe in component?', but I want a method to find if all the subscriptions are unsubscribed. Not how to unsubscribe but to know the count of active subscriptions when a component is destroyed.

Comment: Well, I don't why you want to know the count of the active subscriptions since only the active component will have its subscriptions alive, if you implement this logic everywhere. As you know, every time you enter a new Page, the ngOnDestroy of the previous page will execute, making sure no subscription is left active.